# Gradle is not able to use dependencies from artifactory

Tags: gradle, artifactory

This is the code I have written: Please be notified that the code is working when I enable the flatDir section (commented one in the code), but not working when I want to use Remote Artifactory repository (Means comment the flatDir part):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4+"
   }
  } 

subprojects {
   apply plugin: 'java'
   apply plugin: 'distribution'
   buildDir = new File("$buildPath", project.name)
   ext.distributionDir = new File(project.buildDir, 'distribution')
   sourceSets {
        //SourceSets
   }

   ext.sharedManifest = manifest {
        //Manifests
   }

   tasks.withType(Jar) {
        //Code to generate Jar Artifacts
   }

   //  repositories {
   //     flatDir {
   //          dirs file("$dependencyPath"),
   //      }
   //  }

   allprojects {
      artifactory {
         contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
       publish {
           repository {
               repoKey = 'gradle-dev-local'
               username = "${artifactory_user}"
               password = "${artifactory_password}"
               maven = true
            }
         }
       resolve {
           repository {
               repoKey = 'gradle-dev'
               username = "${artifactory_user}"
               password = "${artifactory_password}"
               maven = true
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
  project(':projectName:ProjectComponent') {
     sourceSets {
       main {
            java { include '/pathToCode/*' }
            }
       }
        dependencies { compile (group: 'jcifs', name: 'jcifs', version: '1.1.11')}

    //******* Publishing Component Jar (Build artifacts on Remote Repository) ********//

     publishing.publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
        groupId 'GroupID'
        artifactId project.name
        version = projVersion
        from components.java
    }
 }
 artifactoryPublish {
     publications(publishing.publications.mavenJava)
   }
}
```

Please suggest the solution. 
Thanks! :-)

Comment: Can you post a snippet from your build file? My assumption is that the buildscript repositories are not configured accordingly.

Comment: Please find code snippet in Answer section:

Comment: Instead of posting an answer, please edit your question and move your snippet into it, then delete your answer if you can.

Comment: Hey, I found the solution. Thanks!!

I just didnot add the repository name in contextUrl and this was causing issue.